# API для управления полноэкранным режимом

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, код или статью для управления полноэкранным режимом браузера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Native Fullscreen JavaScript API (plus jQuery plugin)](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/)