# Изображение на весь экран браузера

Tags: javascript, css, изображения, imageview

На [сайте](https://ebolt.net/ru/catalog/spares/volkswagen-jetta-2/48/?mtype=1&brand=10&model=2) добавлена FOTORAMA - библиотека просмотров изображений.
В функционале которой зашито переключение изображений и конечно же развертывание на весь экран.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Только работает оно не так как нужно, а нужно чтобы изображение растягивалось не просто на всю ширину, а и во весь экран монитора. Чтобы не было видно вкладок, адресной строки и панели страниц.
Как при открытии видео на весь экран.

**КАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ МОЖНО ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ??!**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы скинули скришот - и поставили теги `javascript` и  `css` а кода нету - это нормально ?

Comment: @MaximLensky теги добавил для большего охвата. Предположительно думаю что такое можно решить либо же стандартными методами стилей или же точно скриптами. Если это несоответствие правилам - удалю. Кода никакого нет, просто <img src /> внутри библиотеки.

Comment: если публика будет голосовать за закрытие вопроса то его закроют но на данный момент ни одного голоса за закрытие нету но вопрос на самом деле не является хорошим так как нету кода

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [API для управления полноэкранным режимом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120908/api-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: (в этом ↑ дубликате, кстати, неплохо бы написать развёрнутый ответ, а то там сейчас ответ-ссылка)

Comment: Есть абстрактное изображение которое нужно при нажатии кнопки "Ударь меня" сделать полноэкранным. Возможно это сделать или нет?! Какими способами? Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Решение через **HTML FullScreen API**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Ищем правильный метод
    function FullScreen(element) {
    if(element.requestFullScreen) {
      element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
  }
</script>

<button onClick="FullScreen(document.documentElement);return false;">Ударь меня</button>
```